# Loading configuration options from environment or default values

Tags: go

I have this method that I feel has code repetition that can be improved but since I am new to Go, I am not quite sure how to improve it. I would appreciate if anyone can give me their opinion.

```
func (c *Configuration) loadFromEnvVars(key string, target interface{}, optional bool, defaultValue interface{}) error {
    err := c.configReader.BindEnv(key)
    if err != nil {
        if optional {
            switch target := target.(type) {
            case *string:
                *target = defaultValue.(string)
            case *bool:
                *target = defaultValue.(bool)
            default:
                return fmt.Errorf("default value type provided is not supported")
            }
            return nil
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("%s could not be loaded: %v", key, err)
    }
    switch target := target.(type) {
    case *string:
        *target = c.configReader.GetString(key)
    case *bool:
        *target = c.configReader.GetBool(key)
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("configuration value type provided is not supported")
    }
    return nil
}
```

The two switch statements seems like code repetition but I couldn't figure out how to refactor it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get rid of entirely, you could trade the `switch` cases for `if` statements of course:

```golang
func (c *Configuration) loadFromEnvVars(key string, target interface{}, optional bool, defaultValue interface{}) error {
    err := c.configReader.BindEnv(key)
    if err != nil && !optional {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s could not be loaded: %v", key, err)
    }
    switch target := target.(type) {
    case *string:
        if err == nil {
            *target = defaultValue.(string)
        } else {
            *target = c.configReader.GetString(key)
        }
    case *bool:
        if err == nil {
            *target = defaultValue.(bool)
        } else {
            *target = c.configReader.GetBool(key)
        }
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("configuration value type provided is not supported")
    }
    return nil
}
```

The upside would be that "similar" code is now closer together.

Or, if you really wanted to, you could [use reflection](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) to get rid of the whole thing.  That has an additional runtime cost, though for configuration it likely wouldn't matter.

Something like this:

```golang
func (c *Configuration) loadFromEnvVars(key string, target interface{}, optional bool, defaultValue interface{}) error {
    refTarget := reflect.ValueOf(target).Elem()
    targetType := refTarget.Type()

    var value reflect.Value

    err := c.configReader.BindEnv(key)
    if err == nil {
        value = reflect.ValueOf(c.configReader.Get(key))
    } else {
        if !optional {
            return fmt.Errorf("%s could not be loaded: %v", key, err)
        }
        value = reflect.ValueOf(defaultValue)
    }

    valueType := value.Type()

    if !valueType.AssignableTo(targetType) {
        return fmt.Errorf("incompatible types %v and %v", targetType, valueType)
    }
    
    refTarget.Set(value)

    return nil
}
```

Note that you have to check the types here too to make sure that the assignment call (`Set`) doesn't panic.

Comment: I ended up using the if/else approach....I'm not a bog fan of reflection because besides the performance hit, it feels like magic